# Prettier Pug Plugin

Tags: javascript, performance, typescript

I'm the creator of the plugin [Prettier Pug Plugin](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-pug). Everything works fine and I have a lot of tests because I used TDD

I currently have a large [index.ts](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-pug/blob/master/src/index.ts) ([permalink](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-pug/blob/054b56fe33fa113c178b9a9f655e6ab35cf98c86/src/index.ts)). In this file mainly an array of tokens is iterated in the parse function and each token is specifically treated in a huge switch case.

Please report anything I could improve on this file, especially in terms of performance, but also documentation, outsourcing into smaller files, and Regex improvements.

As a reward for good suggestions, I'll add you to the project's README.md file

---

The index.ts

```
import { Doc, FastPath, format, Options, Parser, ParserOptions, Plugin, util } from 'prettier';
import * as lex from 'pug-lexer';
import { AttributeToken, EndAttributesToken, Token } from 'pug-lexer';
import { DOCTYPE_SHORTCUT_REGISTRY } from './doctype-shortcut-registry';
import { createLogger, Logger, LogLevel } from './logger';
import {
  formatCommentPreserveSpaces,
  options as pugOptions,
  PugParserOptions,
  resolveAttributeSeparatorOption
} from './options';

const { makeString } = util;

const logger: Logger = createLogger(console);
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  logger.setLogLevel(LogLevel.DEBUG);
}

function previousNormalAttributeToken(tokens: Token[], index: number): AttributeToken | undefined {
  for (let i: number = index - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const token: Token = tokens[i];
    if (token.type === 'start-attributes') {
      return;
    }
    if (token.type === 'attribute') {
      if (token.name !== 'class' && token.name !== 'id') {
        return token;
      }
    }
  }
  return;
}

function printIndent(previousToken: Token, indent: string, indentLevel: number): string {
  switch (previousToken?.type) {
    case 'newline':
    case 'outdent':
      return indent.repeat(indentLevel);
    case 'indent':
      return indent;
  }
  return '';
}

function formatText(text: string, singleQuote: boolean): string {
  let result: string = '';
  while (text) {
    const start = text.indexOf('{{');
    if (start !== -1) {
      result += text.slice(0, start);
      text = text.substring(start + 2);
      const end = text.indexOf('}}');
      if (end !== -1) {
        let code = text.slice(0, end);
        code = code.trim();
        code = format(code, { parser: 'babel', singleQuote: !singleQuote, printWidth: 9000 });
        if (code.endsWith(';\n')) {
          code = code.slice(0, -2);
        }
        result += `{{ ${code} }}`;
        text = text.slice(end + 2);
      } else {
        result += '{{';
        result += text;
        text = '';
      }
    } else {
      result += text;
      text = '';
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function unwrapLineFeeds(value: string): string {
  return value.includes('\n')
    ? value
        .split('\n')
        .map((part) => part.trim())
        .join('')
    : value;
}

export const plugin: Plugin = {
  languages: [
    {
      name: 'Pug',
      parsers: ['pug'],
      tmScope: 'text.jade',
      aceMode: 'jade',
      codemirrorMode: 'pug',
      codemirrorMimeType: 'text/x-pug',
      extensions: ['.jade', '.pug'],
      linguistLanguageId: 179,
      vscodeLanguageIds: ['jade']
    }
  ],
  parsers: {
    pug: {
      parse(text: string, parsers: { [parserName: string]: Parser }, options: ParserOptions): Token[] {
        logger.debug('[parsers:pug:parse]:', { text });
        const tokens = lex(text);
        // logger.debug('[parsers:pug:parse]: tokens', JSON.stringify(tokens, undefined, 2));
        // const ast: AST = parse(tokens, {});
        // logger.debug('[parsers:pug:parse]: ast', JSON.stringify(ast, undefined, 2));
        return tokens;
      },
      astFormat: 'pug-ast',
      hasPragma(text: string): boolean {
        return text.startsWith('//- @prettier\n') || text.startsWith('//- @format\n');
      },
      locStart(node: any): number {
        logger.debug('[parsers:pug:locStart]:', { node });
        return 0;
      },
      locEnd(node: any): number {
        logger.debug('[parsers:pug:locEnd]:', { node });
        return 0;
      },
      preprocess(text: string, options: ParserOptions): string {
        logger.debug('[parsers:pug:preprocess]:', { text });
        return text;
      }
    }
  },
  printers: {
    'pug-ast': {
      print(
        path: FastPath,
        {
          printWidth,
          singleQuote,
          tabWidth,
          useTabs,
          attributeSeparator,
          commentPreserveSpaces,
          semi
        }: ParserOptions & PugParserOptions,
        print: (path: FastPath) => Doc
      ): Doc {
        const tokens: Token[] = path.stack[0];

        let result: string = '';
        let indentLevel: number = 0;
        let indent: string = ' '.repeat(tabWidth);
        if (useTabs) {
          indent = '\t';
        }
        let pipelessText: boolean = false;
        let pipelessComment: boolean = false;

        const alwaysUseAttributeSeparator: boolean = resolveAttributeSeparatorOption(attributeSeparator);

        let startTagPosition: number = 0;
        let startAttributePosition: number = 0;
        let previousAttributeRemapped: boolean = false;
        let wrapAttributes: boolean = false;

        const codeInterpolationOptions: Options = {
          singleQuote: !singleQuote,
          printWidth: 9000,
          endOfLine: 'lf'
        };

        if (tokens[0]?.type === 'text') {
          result += '| ';
        }

        for (let index: number = 0; index < tokens.length; index++) {
          const token: Token = tokens[index];
          const previousToken: Token | undefined = tokens[index - 1];
          const nextToken: Token | undefined = tokens[index + 1];
          logger.debug('[printers:pug-ast:print]:', JSON.stringify(token));
          switch (token.type) {
            case 'tag':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              if (!(token.val === 'div' && (nextToken.type === 'class' || nextToken.type === 'id'))) {
                result += token.val;
              }
              startTagPosition = result.length;
              break;
            case 'start-attributes':
              if (nextToken?.type === 'attribute') {
                previousAttributeRemapped = false;
                startAttributePosition = result.length;
                result += '(';
                const start: number = result.lastIndexOf('\n') + 1;
                let lineLength: number = result.substring(start).length;
                logger.debug(lineLength, printWidth);
                let tempToken: AttributeToken | EndAttributesToken = nextToken;
                let tempIndex: number = index + 1;
                while (tempToken.type === 'attribute') {
                  lineLength += tempToken.name.length + 1 + tempToken.val.toString().length;
                  logger.debug(lineLength, printWidth);
                  tempToken = tokens[++tempIndex] as AttributeToken | EndAttributesToken;
                }
                if (lineLength > printWidth) {
                  wrapAttributes = true;
                }
              }
              break;
            case 'attribute': {
              if (typeof token.val === 'string') {
                const surroundedByQuotes: boolean =
                  (token.val.startsWith('"') && token.val.endsWith('"')) ||
                  (token.val.startsWith("'") && token.val.endsWith("'"));
                if (surroundedByQuotes) {
                  if (token.name === 'class') {
                    // Handle class attribute
                    let val = token.val;
                    val = val.substring(1, val.length - 1);
                    val = val.trim();
                    val = val.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
                    const classes: string[] = val.split(' ');
                    const specialClasses: string[] = [];
                    const validClassNameRegex: RegExp = /^-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/;
                    for (const className of classes) {
                      if (!validClassNameRegex.test(className)) {
                        specialClasses.push(className);
                        continue;
                      }
                      // Write css-class in front of attributes
                      const position: number = startAttributePosition;
                      result = [
                        result.slice(0, position),
                        `.${className}`,
                        result.slice(position)
                      ].join('');
                      startAttributePosition += 1 + className.length;
                      result = result.replace(/div\./, '.');
                    }
                    if (specialClasses.length > 0) {
                      token.val = makeString(
                        specialClasses.join(' '),
                        singleQuote ? "'" : '"',
                        false
                      );
                      previousAttributeRemapped = false;
                    } else {
                      previousAttributeRemapped = true;
                      break;
                    }
                  } else if (token.name === 'id') {
                    // Handle id attribute
                    let val = token.val;
                    val = val.substring(1, val.length - 1);
                    val = val.trim();
                    const validIdNameRegex: RegExp = /^-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/;
                    if (!validIdNameRegex.test(val)) {
                      val = makeString(val, singleQuote ? "'" : '"', false);
                      result += `id=${val}`;
                      break;
                    }
                    // Write css-id in front of css-classes
                    const position: number = startTagPosition;
                    result = [result.slice(0, position), `#${val}`, result.slice(position)].join(
                      ''
                    );
                    startAttributePosition += 1 + val.length;
                    result = result.replace(/div#/, '#');
                    if (previousToken.type === 'attribute' && previousToken.name !== 'class') {
                      previousAttributeRemapped = true;
                    }
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }

              const hasNormalPreviousToken: AttributeToken | undefined = previousNormalAttributeToken(
                tokens,
                index
              );
              if (
                previousToken?.type === 'attribute' &&
                (!previousAttributeRemapped || hasNormalPreviousToken)
              ) {
                if (alwaysUseAttributeSeparator || /^(\(|\[|:).*/.test(token.name)) {
                  result += ',';
                }
                if (!wrapAttributes) {
                  result += ' ';
                }
              }
              previousAttributeRemapped = false;

              if (wrapAttributes) {
                result += '\n';
                result += indent.repeat(indentLevel + 1);
              }

              result += `${token.name}`;
              if (typeof token.val === 'boolean') {
                if (token.val !== true) {
                  result += `=${token.val}`;
                }
              } else {
                let val = token.val;
                if (/^((v-bind|v-on|v-slot)?:|v-model|v-on|@).*/.test(token.name)) {
                  // Format Vue expression
                  val = val.trim();
                  val = val.slice(1, -1);
                  val = format(val, {
                    parser: '__vue_expression' as any,
                    ...codeInterpolationOptions
                  });
                  val = unwrapLineFeeds(val);
                  const quotes: "'" | '"' = singleQuote ? "'" : '"';
                  val = `${quotes}${val}${quotes}`;
                } else if (/^(\(.*\)|\[.*\])$/.test(token.name)) {
                  // Format Angular action or binding
                  val = val.trim();
                  val = val.slice(1, -1);
                  val = format(val, {
                    parser: '__ng_interpolation' as any,
                    ...codeInterpolationOptions
                  });
                  val = unwrapLineFeeds(val);
                  const quotes: "'" | '"' = singleQuote ? "'" : '"';
                  val = `${quotes}${val}${quotes}`;
                } else if (/^\*.*$/.test(token.name)) {
                  // Format Angular directive
                  val = val.trim();
                  val = val.slice(1, -1);
                  val = format(val, { parser: '__ng_directive' as any, ...codeInterpolationOptions });
                  const quotes: "'" | '"' = singleQuote ? "'" : '"';
                  val = `${quotes}${val}${quotes}`;
                } else if (/^(["']{{)(.*)(}}["'])$/.test(val)) {
                  // Format Angular interpolation
                  val = val.slice(3, -3);
                  val = val.trim();
                  val = val.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
                  // val = format(val, {
                  //   parser: '__ng_interpolation' as any,
                  //   ...codeInterpolationOptions
                  // });
                  const quotes: "'" | '"' = singleQuote ? "'" : '"';
                  val = `${quotes}{{ ${val} }}${quotes}`;
                } else if (/^["'](.*)["']$/.test(val)) {
                  val = makeString(val.slice(1, -1), singleQuote ? "'" : '"', false);
                } else if (val === 'true') {
                  // The value is exactly true and is not quoted
                  break;
                } else if (token.mustEscape) {
                  val = format(val, {
                    parser: '__js_expression' as any,
                    ...codeInterpolationOptions
                  });
                } else {
                  // The value is not quoted and may be js-code
                  val = val.trim();
                  val = val.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
                  if (val.startsWith('{ ')) {
                    val = `{${val.substring(2, val.length)}`;
                  }
                }

                if (token.mustEscape === false) {
                  result += '!';
                }

                result += `=${val}`;
              }
              break;
            }
            case 'end-attributes':
              if (wrapAttributes) {
                result += '\n';
                result += indent.repeat(indentLevel);
              }
              wrapAttributes = false;
              if (result.endsWith('(')) {
                // There were no attributes
                result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
              } else if (previousToken?.type === 'attribute') {
                result += ')';
              }
              if (nextToken?.type === 'text' || nextToken?.type === 'path') {
                result += ' ';
              }
              break;
            case 'indent':
              result += '\n';
              result += indent.repeat(indentLevel);
              indentLevel++;
              break;
            case 'outdent':
              if (previousToken?.type !== 'outdent') {
                if (token.loc.start.line - previousToken.loc.end.line > 1) {
                  // Insert one extra blank line
                  result += '\n';
                }
                result += '\n';
              }
              indentLevel--;
              break;
            case 'class':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += `.${token.val}`;
              if (nextToken?.type === 'text') {
                result += ' ';
              }
              break;
            case 'eos':
              // Remove all newlines at the end
              while (result.endsWith('\n')) {
                result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
              }
              // Insert one newline
              result += '\n';
              break;
            case 'comment': {
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              if (previousToken && !['newline', 'indent', 'outdent'].includes(previousToken.type)) {
                result += ' ';
              }
              result += '//';
              if (!token.buffer) {
                result += '-';
              }
              result += formatCommentPreserveSpaces(token.val, commentPreserveSpaces);
              if (nextToken.type === 'start-pipeless-text') {
                pipelessComment = true;
              }
              break;
            }
            case 'newline':
              if (previousToken && token.loc.start.line - previousToken.loc.end.line > 1) {
                // Insert one extra blank line
                result += '\n';
              }
              result += '\n';
              break;
            case 'text': {
              let val = token.val;
              let needsTrailingWhitespace: boolean = false;

              if (pipelessText) {
                switch (previousToken?.type) {
                  case 'newline':
                    result += indent.repeat(indentLevel);
                    result += indent;
                    break;
                  case 'start-pipeless-text':
                    result += indent;
                    break;
                }

                if (pipelessComment) {
                  val = formatCommentPreserveSpaces(val, commentPreserveSpaces, true);
                }
              } else {
                if (nextToken && val.endsWith(' ')) {
                  switch (nextToken.type) {
                    case 'interpolated-code':
                    case 'start-pug-interpolation':
                      needsTrailingWhitespace = true;
                      break;
                  }
                }

                val = val.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');

                switch (previousToken?.type) {
                  case 'newline':
                    result += indent.repeat(indentLevel);
                    if (/^ .+$/.test(val)) {
                      result += '|\n';
                      result += indent.repeat(indentLevel);
                    }
                    result += '|';
                    if (/.*\S.*/.test(token.val) || nextToken?.type === 'start-pug-interpolation') {
                      result += ' ';
                    }
                    break;
                  case 'indent':
                    result += indent;
                    result += '|';
                    if (/.*\S.*/.test(token.val)) {
                      result += ' ';
                    }
                    break;
                  case 'interpolated-code':
                  case 'end-pug-interpolation':
                    if (/^ .+$/.test(val)) {
                      result += ' ';
                    }
                    break;
                }

                val = val.trim();
                val = formatText(val, singleQuote);

                val = val.replace(/#(\{|\[)/g, '\\#$1');
              }

              if (
                ['tag', 'id', 'interpolation', 'call', '&attributes', 'filter'].includes(
                  previousToken?.type
                )
              ) {
                val = ` ${val}`;
              }

              result += val;
              if (needsTrailingWhitespace) {
                result += ' ';
              }
              break;
            }
            case 'interpolated-code':
              switch (previousToken?.type) {
                case 'tag':
                case 'class':
                case 'id':
                case 'end-attributes':
                  result += ' ';
                  break;
                case 'start-pug-interpolation':
                  result += '| ';
                  break;
                case 'indent':
                case 'newline':
                case 'outdent':
                  result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
                  result += '| ';
                  break;
              }
              result += token.mustEscape ? '#' : '!';
              result += `{${token.val}}`;
              break;
            case 'code': {
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              if (!token.mustEscape && token.buffer) {
                result += '!';
              }
              result += token.buffer ? '=' : '-';
              let useSemi = semi;
              if (useSemi && (token.mustEscape || token.buffer)) {
                useSemi = false;
              }
              let val = token.val;
              try {
                const valBackup = val;
                val = format(val, {
                  parser: 'babel',
                  ...codeInterpolationOptions,
                  semi: useSemi,
                  endOfLine: 'lf'
                });
                val = val.slice(0, -1);
                if (val.includes('\n')) {
                  val = valBackup;
                }
              } catch (error) {
                logger.warn(error);
              }
              result += ` ${val}`;
              break;
            }
            case 'id': {
              // Handle id attribute
              // Write css-id in front of css-classes
              let lastPositionOfNewline = result.lastIndexOf('\n');
              if (lastPositionOfNewline === -1) {
                // If no newline was found, set position to zero
                lastPositionOfNewline = 0;
              }
              let position: number = result.indexOf('.', lastPositionOfNewline);
              if (position === -1) {
                position = result.length;
              }
              let _indent = '';
              switch (previousToken?.type) {
                case 'newline':
                case 'outdent':
                  _indent = indent.repeat(indentLevel);
                  break;
                case 'indent':
                  _indent = indent;
                  break;
              }
              result = [result.slice(0, position), _indent, `#${token.val}`, result.slice(position)].join(
                ''
              );
              break;
            }
            case 'start-pipeless-text':
              pipelessText = true;
              result += '\n';
              result += indent.repeat(indentLevel);
              break;
            case 'end-pipeless-text':
              pipelessText = false;
              pipelessComment = false;
              break;
            case 'doctype':
              result += 'doctype';
              if (token.val) {
                result += ` ${token.val}`;
              }
              break;
            case 'dot':
              result += '.';
              break;
            case 'block':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += 'block ';
              if (token.mode !== 'replace') {
                result += token.mode;
                result += ' ';
              }
              result += token.val;
              break;
            case 'extends':
              result += 'extends ';
              break;
            case 'path':
              if (['include', 'filter'].includes(previousToken?.type)) {
                result += ' ';
              }
              result += token.val;
              break;
            case 'start-pug-interpolation':
              result += '#[';
              break;
            case 'end-pug-interpolation':
              result += ']';
              break;
            case 'interpolation':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += `#{${token.val}}`;
              break;
            case 'include':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += 'include';
              break;
            case 'filter':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += `:${token.val}`;
              break;
            case 'call': {
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += `+${token.val}`;
              let args: string | null = token.args;
              if (args) {
                args = args.trim();
                args = args.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
                result += `(${args})`;
              }
              break;
            }
            case 'mixin': {
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += `mixin ${token.val}`;
              let args: string | null = token.args;
              if (args) {
                args = args.trim();
                args = args.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
                result += `(${args})`;
              }
              break;
            }
            case 'if': {
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              const match = /^!\((.*)\)$/.exec(token.val);
              logger.debug(match);
              result += !match ? `if ${token.val}` : `unless ${match[1]}`;
              break;
            }
            case 'mixin-block':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += 'block';
              break;
            case 'else':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += 'else';
              break;
            case '&attributes':
              result += `&attributes(${token.val})`;
              break;
            case 'text-html': {
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              const match: RegExpExecArray | null = /^<(.*?)>(.*)<\/(.*?)>$/.exec(token.val);
              logger.debug(match);
              if (match) {
                result += `${match[1]} ${match[2]}`;
                break;
              }
              const entry = Object.entries(DOCTYPE_SHORTCUT_REGISTRY).find(
                ([key]) => key === token.val.toLowerCase()
              );
              if (entry) {
                result += entry[1];
                break;
              }
              result += token.val;
              break;
            }
            case 'each':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += `each ${token.val}`;
              if (token.key !== null) {
                result += `, ${token.key}`;
              }
              result += ` in ${token.code}`;
              break;
            case 'while':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += `while ${token.val}`;
              break;
            case 'case':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += `case ${token.val}`;
              break;
            case 'when':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += `when ${token.val}`;
              break;
            case ':':
              result += ': ';
              break;
            case 'default':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += 'default';
              break;
            case 'else-if':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += `else if ${token.val}`;
              break;
            case 'blockcode':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += '-';
              break;
            case 'yield':
              result += printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
              result += 'yield';
              break;
            case 'slash':
              result += '/';
              break;
            default:
              throw new Error('Unhandled token: ' + JSON.stringify(token));
          }
        }

        logger.debug(result);
        return result;
      },
      embed(
        path: FastPath,
        print: (path: FastPath) => Doc,
        textToDoc: (text: string, options: Options) => Doc,
        options: ParserOptions
      ): Doc | null {
        // logger.debug('[printers:pug-ast:embed]:', JSON.stringify(path, undefined, 2));
        return null;
      },
      insertPragma(text: string): string {
        return `//- @prettier\n${text}`;
      }
    }
  },
  options: pugOptions as any,
  defaultOptions: {}
};

export const languages = plugin.languages;
export const parsers = plugin.parsers;
export const printers = plugin.printers;
export const options = plugin.options;
export const defaultOptions = plugin.defaultOptions;
```

---

Edit:
I ran the Node Profiler with `NODE_ENV=production node --prof benchmark/index.js` and `node --prof-process isolate-0x1042cd000-45853-v8.log > processed.txt`

Result: https://gist.github.com/Shinigami92/ce96f31f8d9d928f9e5cb3c7438a03cd

Comment: Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3

Comment: BTW you changes didn't incorporate everything I said, for example `case 'attribute'` is still ridiculously huge. Splitting code up is paramount to good code.

Comment: @Peilonrayz currently working on this :)

Comment: Ah good good. Ignore me :)

Answer (score 4):

Your code is a massive god-file. This is never a good idea and is seriously hard to read. Given the raw magnitude it makes me just want to run away.

The Cyclomatic Complexity, halstead metrics and maintainability index of your class is almost definitely the lowest grade it could possibly be in all of them. I suggest you looking for a tool like [Radion](https://radon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for JavaScript/TypeScript. These metrics are useful as they say how readable your code is.

The large `switch (token.type)` would be better described as a class. The following is just to showcase the structure, and does not work.

```
class TokenHandler {
    tag(...) {
        let result = printIndent(previousToken, indent, indentLevel);
        if (!(token.val === 'div' && (nextToken.type === 'class' || nextToken.type === 'id'))) {
          result += token.val;
        }
        this.startTagPosition = result.length;
        return result;
    }
}

let tokenHandler = new TokenHandler();

...

logger.debug('[printers:pug-ast:print]:', JSON.stringify(token));
// switch (token.type)
result += tokenHandler[token.type](...);
```

This would come with a couple of benefits.

- The methods, like `tag`, would be self contained. Anyone that has never read your code before can come along and mutate it with ease.
  You should be able to see that I've probably butchered how it actually should be, as your code is just far too complex for me to be able to replicate it correctly with ease.
- You have the ability to define the constants of the function on `TokenHandler` in its constructor. Allowing for a couple of `this.` in your code, but fundamentally the same amount of code.
- Your pug-ast `print` function can have a reduction in its size. This allows for easier maintenance on the function, as you don't have to skip a couple hundred lines to understand what the code is doing.

I would also suggest breaking your `case 'attribute'` into more functions, as currently it's also far to large for a single function.

Currently I find your code to be unmaintainable, and in need of a massive re-write so you use at most 20 line long functions. This doesn't help with performance, but I always get the code to be as readable and maintainable as can be before starting on performance. And since I can barely comprehend your code, I won't be able to improve the performance.

Comment: Nice! I never thought about using a class, that could definitely work. I also take a look at Radon, I've never heard of it before. With this answer you are currently the bounty holder.

Comment: @Shinigami I'm a Python developer so it's a Python tool, but I'd hope there is a JavaScript equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Just some quick/general thoughts here, not really an in-depth analysis.

Regarding performance, it's imperative to use devtools performance profiler (or its simpler version "JavaScript profiler" in Chrome) and optionally other more specialized tools for node.js, etc. Otherwise you'll get a rehashing of the well-known practices which most likely have little to no influence in this case.

For example, you do a lot of string concatenation but I would instantly suggest using an array which can then be quickly converted into a string by using Uint8Array+TextDecoder API or via feeding 8kB chunks to String.fromCharCode or plain arr.join('') if you store strings.

Regarding RegExp, things like `/^prefix(.*)suffix$/` can cause catastrophic backtracking (like half a minute) on some inputs so it's best to split such an expression in two or apply [other preventive solutions](https://javascript.info/regexp-catastrophic-backtracking), even use plain-string checks where possible via `str.startsWith('prefix') && str.endsWith('suffix')` and then `slice()` the string.

Regarding splitting, one thing to pay attention to is the deoptimization of large functions due to various heuristics in V8 (and possibly other js engines), partially when the shape of function parameters changes, which should be indicated as such in devtools profiler and for which you can find more info on V8 blogs, IIRC. Here's also some: https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-perf

Comment: Thank you in advance for the suggestions.

I'm currently still having problems with the `Uint8Array` + `TextDecoder` or `arr.join('')` tactic, I still don't know how to write retroactively into the existing result string. Example: https://github.com/prettier/plugin-pug/blob/d89adf05c9052cd5edcf309d8ac46803520f1621/src/index.ts#L223-L227

RegExp: I will check with jsPerf / Benchmark.js if multiple `startsWith` are faster than in example `/^((v-bind|v-on|v-slot)?:|v-model|v-on|@).*/`

Also I will learn some things about heuristics in V8 and node.js profiling

Comment: 1) looks like a job for `splice()`, assuming we're talking about normal arrays as Uint8Array doesn't seem usable in your case after all due to being too rigid, 2) just in case, startsWith isn't the core of my regexp suggestion, it's only a minor thing for super trivial cases, but the dangerous thing is an unconstrained `.*` in the middle.

Comment: You will receive the bounty if there is no better answer by 12:00 noon on Sunday